# How to use .tga picture to cover .dae 3D model?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

```
// create a new scene
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Iron_Man.dae")!
// retrieve the SCNView
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

// set the scene to the view
scnView.scene = scene
```

I use Xcode to change *.scn file into *.dea file in art.scnassets floder. And there is some .tga picture.  how to use .tga picture to cover .dae 3D model?

Comment: i do want to know